# JQUERY - Add Margin to Multiple Objects

Tags: jquery

I currently setting margin like below successfully:

```
    $('div#container_join_messages').css({'margin-right': '56.5%'});
    $('div#container_join_errors').css({'margin-right': '56.5%'});
    $('div#container_join_now').css({'margin-right': '56.5%'});
```

Is there a way to combine these into one line?
Tried the following unsuccesfully:

```
    ($('div#container_join_messages'), $('div#container_join_errors'), $('div#container_join_now')).css({'margin-right': '56.5%'});
```

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#container_join_messages, #container_join_errors, #container_join_now').css({'margin-right': '56.5%'});
```

You need to place the commas inside the selector string.

You can read the documentation about this here: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

[Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52233/alan-geleynse)'s answer is perfect. But if all of those element had a class then it would be easy to manipulate, more semantic and readable code.

```
$('.theClass').css('margin-right', '56.5%');
```

Also you can use [jQuery child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) if all of those divs (and no other divs)wrapped by another div.

```
$('#wrappingDiv > div').css('margin-right', '56.5%');
```